# Get EOS multinode blockchain existing peers information C#

Tags: nodeos, full-node, net-plugin, c#

I have an EOS blockchain with connecting Peers (One genesis node and 3 connecting peers). I can get their information using the NET API Plugin, by the command `cleos net peers`. For the rest of the data, I am using the library `eos-sharp`. I need these peer's information using C# (p2p address, node id, chain id, head block etc). Can anybody help and guide how can I achieve this task? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eossharp doesn't contain the functionality to query the NET API and is not maintained anymore... you could just call the NET API endpoints yourself, see here https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/net_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/connections

Comment: Okay, thank you for the reply!